# Sharepoint List Column Title with "." in title gets listed as "#" in the record set

Tags: vba, sharepoint

In SharePoint I have manually created a list and I gave one of the columns the title "Impl. Date" to match a heading in the excel sheet that the list will be populated from.

In SharePoint it looks like:

[image: SharePoint header]

when I look at the field name for the record set, the "." is replaced with "#" as seen here:

[image: rst name]

The portion of the code where I am replacing the existing SharePoint table looks like like the following and the error occurs during the 5th iteration of nCounter loop. This is when Headers(nCounter) = "Impl. Date".

```
Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

With cnt
    .ConnectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=0;RetrieveIds=Yes;DATABASE=http://my.company.com/SubSite/;LIST=" & GUID(Foldername) & ";"
    .Open
End With

'set SQL string to filter the list to match what is to be done.
mySQL = "DELETE * FROM [" & SharepointListName & "];"
'activate SQL command
cnt.Execute mySQL, , adCmdText

mySQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & SharepointListName & "];"

rst.Open mySQL, cnt, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

For lCounter = Headerrow + 1 To LastRow
    rst.AddNew
    For nCounter = 1 To LastCol + 1
        rst.Fields(Headers(nCounter)) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lCounter, nCounter).Value
    Next nCounter

    '    Select Case SharepointListName
    '        Case "NSP Index"
    '            rst.Fields("Region") = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & lCounter).Text
    '            rst.Fields("NSP") = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & lCounter).Text
    '            rst.Fields("Title") = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & lconter).Text
    '            rst.Fields("Version") = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & lconter).Text
    '            rst.Fields("Impl. Date") = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & lconter).Text
    '            rst.Fields("Issue Date") = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & lconter).Text
    '            rst.Fields("Link") = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & lconter).Text
    '        Case "OPSD Index", "SSD Index", "MTOD Index"
    '
    '        Case "OPSS Index", "SSP Index"
    '
    '    End Select

    '    rst.Fields("FileLink") = filecaption & filelink
    rst.Update
Next lCounter
```

The error box I am getting is:

[image: error box]

right now I am assuming the reason "The item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested nam or ordinal" is being caused by the # not matching .

Am I wrong in my assumption?  **Is there a way to change the SharePoint field name to match the Excel Name?  Different methodology I should be using?**

Comment: Maybe you should change your column headers to prevent such errors from happening. Using spaces and most special (non alphanumeric) characters in fields is a recipe for disaster. The notable exception is _

Comment: The source Excel file were the list is located is generated by a third party system.  I am trying to match as much as possible the excel file to to the share point list.  My current work around is `REPLACE(Headers(ncounter),".","#")` and it seemed to work. but it seems like an ugly solution.

Comment: My condolences, that sounds like a really ugly situation.